# QuickBooks error message: Transaction not in balance

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

QB desktop shows the below error while Modifting ReceiveCustomerPayment

> "There was an error when modifying a ReceivePayment.  QuickBooks error
> message: Transaction not in balance.""

```
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ReceivePaymentModRq requestID="2">
      <ReceivePaymentMod>
        <TxnID>E4C-1673793968</TxnID>
        <EditSequence>1673793968</EditSequence>
        <CustomerRef>
          <FullName>D.R.H:Sawgrass Lakes:4257 Broomsedge Circle</FullName>
        </CustomerRef>
        <TxnDate>2023-01-11</TxnDate>
        <RefNumber>6866666</RefNumber>
        <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
        <PaymentMethodRef>
          <FullName>Check</FullName>
        </PaymentMethodRef>
        <AppliedToTxnMod>
          <TxnID>E45-1673793562</TxnID>
          <PaymentAmount>76.50</PaymentAmount>
        </AppliedToTxnMod>
      </ReceivePaymentMod>
    </ReceivePaymentModRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Any help is appreciable..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saving a payment of:

```
<TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
```

And of that `0.00`, you are applying `76.50` to an invoice:

```
        <AppliedToTxnMod>
          <TxnID>E45-1673793562</TxnID>
          <PaymentAmount>76.50</PaymentAmount>
        </AppliedToTxnMod>
```

How are you applying `76.50` to an invoice, when the payment is only for `0.00`? That is what QuickBooks is trying to tell you.

The `TotalAmount` should equal the sum of all of your `PaymentAmount` tags.

Comment: Thanks @Keith Palmer Jr. Is it like a any chance to become total amount as zero if invoice payment completed?

Comment: It does not make any sense to pay someone $0.00. If you're making a payment, the TotalAmount will always be greater than 0.